# Update Employee Script

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a provider table which has our employees information in it. It is set up like this.

Provider_Data

- PID
- PROFIRST
- PROMI
- PROLAST

When I typically use the data from this table I will use a case statement(this might be the wrong technique I am thinking).

```
Select ln.Location_ID,
       ln.Note_Author,
       lc.Customdata AS Residents
       FROM Location_Notes_Data LN 
       JOIN Location_Notes_Custom_Data lc 
            ON ln.Noteid = lc.Noteid
```

I changed up my explanation here a little. I use this code to get the location ID, Note_Author, and then Customdata from another table. But when the location_Id and the Note_author is populated it is like this: 491-12 and 122083, its not listing the name of them. This is why I was using a `CASE` statement and manually typing them in.

The Note_Author = PID. My problem that I am running into is when a new employee comes on or when an employee leaves my script will not reflect this unless I manually go in and add/remove them.

Comment: Well, that's probably because you're hardcoding values into the CASE. If so, what could you do? I don't know, to few data to process. Maybe **joining** it to some other table would fix it, but I'm not sure as I don't have enough information.

Comment: I added a little more code. I could join the Provider_Data table as well, but wouldn't this just list all the PID's? How could I tie them all together without using a CASE?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you just need a `join`.  Your question doesn't have much detail, but something like this:

```
select n.*, pd.*
from notes n left join
     provider_data pd
     on n.note_author = pd.pid
```

Comment: I added some more detail to the original post. So you're saying I could `JOIN` the 3rd table and have that table populate the Location_Id and Note_Author?

Answer (score 0):

You can update a table from joined tables. I gather you are trying to update employee records as they move in or out of your company? I'm not entirely sure, but if there exists a mapping between tables, you can code the update statement something like this.

```
UPDATE  e
SET     e.Location_ID = ln.Location_ID
        ,e.Residents = lc.CustomData
FROM    Employee e
        INNER JOIN Location_Notes_Data AS ln ON ln.Note_Author = e.PID
        INNER JOIN Location_Notes_Custom_Data lc ON ln.Noteid = lc.Noteid
```

Comment: I am not trying to update the employees records. I am trying to run a report using a field note_author (employees name), but I want the report to be updated when employees come and go. If I hard code with `case` statement then if we get a new employee, I would have to go back and manually add that person.